# mdSidenav service can't find a component when it's inside an Angular component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-1.5

I'm trying to figure out why an Angular `.component()` which has a `<md-sidenav>` directive can't be located from the own component's controller. Angular throws the following error:

> No instance found for handle menu

The whole component is:

```
function controller($mdSidenav) {
    $mdSidenav("menu").open();
}
controller.$inject = ["$mdSidenav"];

components.component("sideAppMenu", {
    controller: controller,
    controllerAs: "model",
    templateUrl: "path/to/template"
});
```

...and its template is:

```
<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="menu">
    hello world
</md-sidenav>
```

If I move the whole `<md-sidenav>` to my `index.html` (i.e. outside any directive/component), `$mdSidenav` can locate the whole Angular Material component.

What's going wrong here? Am I missing some detail?

**I can confirm the whole component is rendered. That is, the template is located and injected successfully**.

### Update

I could figure out where's the issue: it's about the component life-cycle. If I use `$timeout` to try to access the so-called Angular Material component after a while the controller code is reached, `$mdSidenav` **can locate the component**:

```
function controller($mdSidenav, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function() {
        // OK!!!!!!!!
        $mdSidenav("menu").open();
        debugger;
    },3000);
}
controller.$inject = ["$mdSidenav", "$timeout"];
```

If the issue is *when to access the component*, if it's when controller is initialized, when should I try to access an Angular Material component?

Answer (score 1):

I could solve my issue using the `md-is-locked-open` `<md-sidenav>` directive/component attribute.

Since I just wanted to lock the menu opened for the entire app's life-cycle, this is fine for me.

I suspect that Angular Material developers didn't cover my use case but the case of requiring a service once the view is already loaded and you perform a `click` or any event...

BTW, I'll leave this Q&A open to new answers so we can understand why my scenario wasn't working...